# Did MPMusicPlayerController change with iOS 5?

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

I had an app which worked correctly in iOS 4.3, after upgrading to iOS 5 it behaves in another way.
After executing these lines on iOS 4.3 mp.playbackState is set to MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused, however in iOS 5 it is still set to MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying.

```
MPMusicPlayerController *mp = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
if(mp.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying)
    [mp pause];
```

I assume that playbackState is not updated within the same event loop, is it ok?

Comment: I had to make a similar workaround described [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118726/getting-wrong-playback-state-in-mp-music-player-controller-in-ios-5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is:

```
MPMusicPlaybackState playbackState = [musicPlayer playbackState];
```

in iOS5 is not always correct.

This work for me:

```
if (!isPlay) 
{    
   isPlay = TRUE;
   [appPlayer play];
}
else 
{
   isPlay = FALSE;
   [appPlayer pause];
}
```

Comment: I had to do something like this because I couldn't figure out another solution.

Comment: I have the same issue, is this a bug? Do you guys see NULL as the .playbackState sometimes?

Comment: No, I never saw NULL. Eventually I used the **MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification** because there I got the correct playbackState.

Comment: These bugs in iOS SDK are such timer-wasters, our lives are consumed by Apple's carelessness and unwillingness to fix their own mistakes.